# How do i edit the original message after defering the interaction in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a slash command using discord.py with a button that would first defer the interaction to thinking (to prevent interaction timeouts) then i want to edit the original message (the one with the button view) but i seem to be unable to do that

`original command`

```py
@group.command(name="completion", description="Text completion and code generation from a prompt")
@app_commands.describe(prompt="The text generation prompt - no default", temperature="Sampling temperature - 0.5")
async def completion(self, interaction, prompt: str, temperature: float = 0.5):
    msg = await interaction.response.defer(thinking=True)
    view = Regen(prompt, temperature, msg)
    api_json = await completion(prompt, temperature)
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.set_author(name=f"Text Completion  ·  {temperature}/1")
    embed.description = f"**{prompt}** {api_json}"
    await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed, view=view)
```

`button class`

```py
@ui.button(label="Regenerate", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji="<:regen:1060690906547765409>")
    async def regen(self, interaction: discord.Integration, button: ui.Button):
        try:
            await interaction.response.defer(thinking=True, ephemeral=True)
            api_json = await completion(self.prompt, self.temperature)
            embed = discord.Embed()
            embed.set_author(name=f"Text Completion  ·  {self.temperature}/1")
            embed.description = f"**{self.prompt}** {api_json}"
            await self.msg.edit(embed=embed)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

What i was expecting was that editing the `msg` object would edit the followup response in the original message, but it edits the followup of the button instead, creating a new message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Button Interaction, you can get the original interaction/message using `await interaction.original_response()`. From that, you can edit the message.

```
@ui.button(label="Regenerate", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji="<:regen:1060690906547765409>")
    async def regen(self, interaction: discord.Integration, button: discord.ui.Button):
        try:
            api_json = await completion(self.prompt, self.temperature)
            embed = discord.Embed()
            embed.set_author(name=f"Text Completion  ·  {self.temperature}/1")
            embed.description = f"**{self.prompt}** {api_json}"
            msg = await interaction.original_response()
            await msg.edit(embed=embed)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

You can read more about `await interaction.original_response()` here:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.original_response